# Ошибка кодировки при считывании данных с сайта

Tags: c#, кодировка

Есть проблема, а именно ошибка кодировки при считывании данных с сайта при помощи кода на C#. Вся кириллица из нормальных символов превращается в нечто подобное: РЇРїРѕРЅСЃРєРёР№ СЏР·С‹Рє. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно побороть. Для получения данных использую следующий под:

```
        WebRequest request =  WebRequest.Create(@"http://exclusiveblog.ru/markup/problema-s-utf8-v-denwere");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default);
        string htmlCode = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
```

а так же этот:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
             {
               string sitetext = client.DownloadString("http://http://exclusiveblog.ru/markup/problema-s-utf8-v-denwere");
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо.